# Netflix Client on VB.NET, How to make it run Silverlight and needed extensions?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, webbrowser-control

I'm developing a netflix client on vb.net, and i need it to run silverlight and needed extensions that netflix requires to display the video stream.
how can i change webbrowser from default to another one that works with my needs, and what browser is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a different web rendering engine you should try the Gecko web engine. From my experience it is much faster than the traditional IE engine and more compatible with plugins and web content. The engine integrates well into VB.NET applications so using it in your program should work. The engine itself does stream videos from netflix if that's the intent. you can download this rendering engine just from searching it but for convinience I'll put a link to a site where you can find it [here.](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/)